# How to select text in an input after a change in Angular at the right time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selection

I have an input box. When the text changes, I need to select the text. I understand that there are many events going on and I need to wait for them to finish. I put in a timeout and it works. However I don't want to rely on a constant time. Is there any way how to select the text when Angular is finished changing the text?

Example HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="{{txt}}">
<button ng-click="select()">Press</button>
```

Example JS:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.txt = "Hello World";
    $scope.select = function () {
        $scope.txt = "Bye World";
        // doesn't work, too early
        document.querySelector("input").setSelectionRange(0, 4);
        // works
        $interval(function () {
            document.querySelector("input").setSelectionRange(0, 4);
        }, 10, 1);
    }
});
```

[Working example is JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1jjztodj/)

**EDIT**: From the answers it looks like using timeouts (even with 0 delay) is a common practice, but the question remains whether this will guarantee that the selection happens after Angular finishes updating the text.

Comment: do you want to put delay ?

Comment: @Ved no, I want to avoid using delays and timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $timeout with 0 delay for this purpose.

```
$timeout(function(){
    document.querySelector("input").setSelectionRange(0, 4); 
});
```

Angular changes the DOM in next `$digest` cycle, it is extremely fast, but it won't be available as soon as you run `$scope.x = ??`. Normally we would use `$timeout` to "wait" in this case.

Comment: I see, is it a common practice? And guaranteed that it will happen after the text is changed?

Comment: Yea it's quite common. I can't guarantee for them, though, you could try it out a few times for yourself =)

Answer (score 1):

$timeout 0 delay is in fact good enough since angular's dirty checking (and $digest cycle) happens synchronously. (0 delay would only fire up when the current process is free).

If you really really want to guarantee it, here's how:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.txt = "Hello World";
    $scope.select = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.txt = "Bye World";
            });
            document.querySelector("input").setSelectionRange(0, 4);
        });
    };
});
```

You have to use timeout to wrap the $apply, because the scope function would trigger a $digest and you cannot call $digest within a $digest cycle($apply calls $digest for you). $apply here guarantee the scope variable is updated, hence your setSelectionRange would only happen after the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `$timeout`, you can fire event with `ng-blur`. A blur event fires when an element has lost focus.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mtngqeu/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form>
            <input type="text" ng-blur="select()" value="{{txt}}">
            <button>Press</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Script:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {       
    $scope.select = function () {    
        document.querySelector("input").setSelectionRange(0, 4);
    }
});
```