# ElementRef security risk angular 2

Tags: angular

Why ElementRef is not secure to use if so, what we can use instead?

I'm been using this ElementRef to see or watch a specific html tag and then to send as specific width after is initialize, but if this open a security risk I will not use it, and to be honest I don't understand why angular 2 teams allow this kind security flaws in their framework.

What is the secure and best technique to use? My test component below:

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-standard',
          template: ` <button type="button" #buttonW></button>`,

        })
        export class standardComponent implements OnInit {

          name: string = 'app-standard';
          viewWidthButton: any;

          @ViewChild( 'buttonW' ) elButtonW: ElementRef; 


          constructor() { 

            this.viewWidthButton = this.elButtonW.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
            console.log ('button width: ' + this.viewWidthButton);
          }

          ngOnInit() {
          }

        }
```

Angular 2 page reference:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://angularjs.blogspot.com.tr/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)

Comment: the recommend solution on your link still using ElementRef, not sure if it's safe

Comment: A risk is not a flaw. And the risk is not introduced by Angular. It has nothing to do with `ElementRef` itself. Your code doesn't do anything risky.

Answer (score 19):

Using `ElementRef` doesn't directly make your site less secure. The Angular team is just saying *"Hey, you may use this, just be careful with it"*.

If you are only using an `ElementRef` to **get** information, like in your example a certain width, there is no security risk involved at all. It's a different story when you use an `ElementRef` to **modify the DOM**. There, potential threats can arise. Such an example could be:

```
@ViewChild('myIdentifier')
myIdentifier: ElementRef

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.onclick = someFunctionDefinedBySomeUser;
}
```

The problem with this is that it gets inserted directly into the DOM, skipping the Angular sanitisation mechanisms. What are sanitisation mechanisms? Usually, if something in the DOM is changed via Angular, Angular makes sure it's nothing dangerous. However, when using ElementRef to insert something into the DOM, Angular can't guarantee this. So it becomes *your* responsibility that nothing bad enters the DOM when using `ElementRef`. An important keyword here is XSS (Cross-Site Scripting).

To summarise: If you poll the DOM for information, you are safe. If you modify the DOM using `ElementRef`, make sure the modifications don't possibly contain malicious code.

Comment: but cant a hacker put a breakpoint in there and do whatever they want with the element ref?

Comment: @squirrelareduck, If I'm understanding your question, at that point the hacker would be hacking their own computer.

Comment: @thank_you That's the point. It doesn't seem like a valid security concern since a user has access to the dev console at all times and can simply make these changes with or without the nativeElement.

Comment: @Jason Long The risk is mainly about content generated by someone else. If I in this post write <script>alert("Hello!")</script>, nothing happens when you come to this page, because SO sanitizes my comment (probably both in front end and back end). This sanitation will not happen automatically when inserting things through ElementRef, and that opens a risk for XSS.