# How to use ElementRef security risk free in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am confused about ElementRef using in Angular 8. I read that permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks. I am scared about it. Experts, please guide me. My code is mentioned below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

then

```
@ViewChild("elem", { static: false }) elem: ElementRef;
```

and use it as:

```
this.elem.nativeElement.classList.add('current');
```

Another, page I use the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){}
```

and use as:

```
let elements = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".roundIcon");
console.log(elements);
```

Please guide that two methods are XSS attacks safe?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If u use @ViewChild /@ViewChildren, that is the secure angular way. Dont use Documenta.getElementById for example, as this is not the angular way and insecure

Comment: Okay. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: This is quite a comprehensive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834226/elementref-security-risk-angular-2